# Create one row DataFrame from dict, where one of value is a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A little problem that leads me to two (or even 3) questions. And I have some difficulties to google the answer.

Here the very simple example :

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> year = 2023
>>> item = 'obj'
>>> res_dict = {"year" : year, "values" : my_list, "name" : item }
>>> print(res_dict)
{'year': 2023, 'values': [1, 2, 3], 'name': 'obj'}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(res_dict)
>>> print(df)
   year  values name
0  2023       1  obj
1  2023       2  obj
2  2023       3  obj
```

My problem that I want a slightly different DataFrame.

My first idea was to create a DataFrame where in values we store a list.
So something like this :

```
   year     values  name
0  2023  [1, 2, 3]   obj
```

But, and here is the first question : it seems that while it's possible to put list into cell of DataFrame it"s not really a good idea.
If it's so...

The second question. How could I instead create a DataFrame with columns for each element of my list ?
To get something like this :

```
   year  values1  values2  values3  name
0  2023        1        2        3   obj
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your first question - just enclose your list in another list, so when it iterates through the values it gets the one list.

```
import pandas as pd
my_list = [1,2,3]
year = 2023
item = 'obj'
res_dict = {"year" : year, "values" : [my_list], "name" : item}
print(res_dict)
df = pd.DataFrame(res_dict)
print(df)
```

```
   year     values name
0  2023  [1, 2, 3]  obj
```

And here's your second, expanding values into your data dictionary - just remember to pass in an index, as the df only has one row.

```
import pandas as pd
my_list = [1,2,3]
year = 2023
item = 'obj'
res_dict = {"year" : year, **{"values" + str(n+1):item for n,item in enumerate(my_list)}, "name" : item}
print(res_dict)
df = pd.DataFrame(res_dict,index=[0])
print(df)
```

```
   year  values1  values2  values3 name
0  2023        1        2        3  obj
```

Both of these solutions would strike me as a little weird if I saw them in live code, pandas is designed to be rather like a spreadsheet, so having lists in data cells is awkward and not natural, but you can definitely do it. The second solution isn't really well normalized (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: About discussion of weird solutions. I'd like to have some advice. In fact I have some data for each year. Almost all of data is just a numbers, but one of them is a list. For example a number of sales in each quarter of the year ([1, 2, 3, 4] : I have one sale in first 3 months, 2 sales in second quarter etc). As all others data is just the numbers it seems strange to create multiples rows. So I think about these two solutions. Insert a list or convert this list to separate columns. Do you have a better idea ?

Comment: If I were working on stores and a list of their sales, I probably wouldn't use pandas to store the data, but rather native python classes - ie, a store class with a list of sales. Pandas is very good for exporting data for user review, though.

Comment: it's not a software. Globally it's just to get some data, do some calculations and then plot the graphs. So the choice of DataFrames seemed like a good idea for me.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your second question, you could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [1, 2, 3]
year = 2023
item = 'obj'

res_dict = {"year": year, "name": item}

for i, value in enumerate(my_list):
    column_name = f"value{i+1}"
    res_dict[column_name] = value

df = pd.DataFrame(res_dict, index=[0])
print(df)
```

```
   year name  value1  value2  value3
0  2023  obj       1       2       3
```

In answer to your first question, it depends what you need to do with that data and how you want to access it once it's in the df.

Comment: by 21 seconds! well done

Comment: @doine : Will you be upset is I accept Carbon answers? You answer is perfectly correct, but I found Carbon answer a little bit more pythonic and a little bit more detailed.